# Unable to install "@react-navigation/stack" using `npm install @react-navigation/stack` in reactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile-application, react-navigation-stack, expo

In **React Native** application to make a navigation need to install **@react-navigation/stack** using `npm install @react-navigation/stack` and I have tried it and failed each and every times.

**NPM version:** `7.19.1`
**Node version:** `v15.14.0`
**Expo version:** `4.8.1`

After running `npm install @react-navigation/stack` this command I have faced the below error is given,

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: @react-navigation/native@3.8.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/native
npm ERR!   @react-navigation/native@"^3.8.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.0" from @react-navigation/stack@6.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm ERR!   @react-navigation/stack@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/imdadul/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/imdadul/.npm/_logs/2021-08-04T07_46_39_555Z-debug.log
```

**Note:** Please concern the attached file and who have knowledge about this will be helpful to help me. **Advanced Thanks!**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have dependency conflict which means that the dependency is **incorrect** and **potentially** broken. You could try to run the command with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps` and see if that helps.

> ```
> npm install @react-navigation/stack --force
> ```

or

> ```
> npm install @react-navigation/stack --legacy-peer-deps
> ```

Sometimes removing the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file and run the command `npm install @react-navigation/stack` or try `npm cache clean --force` can work.